# Excel Copy Paste Way in Python

Tags: python, pandas, copy-paste

I have a data frame as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2,1],[4,5,6],[10,20,30]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

    A   B   C
0   3   2   1
1   4   5   6
2  10  20  30
```

Is there any way in python to mimic copy and paste function in excel? For example I want to copy paste row 0 column A and B and paste them into row 0 column B and C, such that it will become

```
    A   B   C
0   3   3   2
1   4   5   6
2  10  20  30
```

In a small data frame, I can use:

```
df.loc[0,'C'] = df.loc[0,'B']
df.loc[0,'B'] = df.loc[0,'A']
```

But my original data frame is sizable and I prefer not to do this one element by one element. 
I was also trying to do:

```
df.loc[0,['A','B']] = df.loc[0,['B','C']]
```

But my data in row 0 column A becomes NaN.

So is there a way of doing things similar like doing copy paste in excel in python (simply block a range of data, copy them and paste them on top of another existing data)? Thanks

Comment: The columns name do matter when you assign the value , so adding .values or to_numpy() to remove the impact of index

Comment: I did this, but like I mentioned above: I have a large data set, so I want the code to block certain range of row and paste it on top of another range of existing row. Thanks.

Comment: @anky_91 if you post an answer, let me know and I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### anky_91's answer

```
df.loc[0, ['B', 'C']] = df.loc[0, ['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
```

---

#### `shift`

There are many ways you can use shift. This is just one.

```
df.update(df.shift(axis=1)[['B', 'C']])
```

---

For reasons that I'm not happy about, you can provide a `fill_value` to `shift` to preserve the integer `dtype`

```
df.update(df.shift(axis=1, fill_value=0)[['B', 'C']])
```

Answer (score 0):

This mostly feels like a bad idea, but if it's what you really want to do, you can use `.iloc` to address columns by number and just shift them:

```
In [56]: df.iloc[0, 1:] = df.iloc[0, :-1].values

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
    A   B   C
0   3   3   2
1   4   5   6
2  10  20  30
```

Comment: Hi Randy, is there any possibility to take a range of columns by their names instead of number? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as noted in anky_91's comment, you can just flip your assignment around with `.loc` and use `.values`/`.to_numpy()` if you want to assign them by name.